# Most efficient way of creating a mirrored set of limbs/details?

Tags: mesh, mirror-modifier

So I'm creating some limbs on a model as seen in the image below. I'm creating the left side and then using a mirror modifier across the body.

When it comes time to animate/export I apply the mirror modifier, then I go into edit mode and separate the right side, rename it, and change the origin.

This works fine, but when I have to do this for a lot of pieces it can take a while.

I know armatures have a symmetrize option that works really well, and I'm just wondering if there's anything more efficient than what I'm doing for meshes without armatures.

[image]

Comment: Why are you bothering to seperate the two halves and move the origins if they're mirror images of each other? Just apply the modifier, create your armature for one side and mirror that. - Job done.

Comment: Because when I export them into Unity, the modifiers are applied and then they pivot point doesn't work as intended.

Additionally, I want to be able to move them independently of each other.

Comment: You can select all the objects and go to the Object drop down menu in Object mode. Click Object->Convert->Mesh. This will apply all the mirror modifiers on all the objects at once. You can then go into edit mode with all of them selected, select the vertices on one side and separate them with separate->By selection. Alternatively you can just make the objects on one side and then apply rotation and scale, duplicate them and scale them to -1 with the cursor being on the body. Apply scale again on those and fix the normals

Comment: The separate selection method is what I'm currently doing. The scale -1 method seems faster, but is there a fast way to apply the opposite position to multiple objects? Because otherwise I have to apply position one by one which is also slow.